# assign a member function to a function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

If I have two classes like this :

```
class A
{
    public:
        int *(*fun)( const int &t );
        A( int *( *f )( const int &t ) ) : fun( f ) {}
};

class B
{
    private:
        float r;

        int *f(const int &t)
        {
            return new int( int( r ) + t );
        }
        A a;
        B() : a( A( f ) ) {}
};
```

This results in compiler error.

I want to assign `f` to `a`'s function pointer.

The thing is that `A` can be used by many classes not just `B` so I can't simply define `fun` as `B::*fun`.

None of the posts I've found on the internet and here on stackoverflow  address the issue of using the function pointers with many classes each having its own member function but the same prototype.

So what to do?

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: _"I found many results on the net and on SO but none of them address the issue of"_ Really? I answered one of those just yesterday, if memory serves.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hmm well "just yesterday" is after my search :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And a few days before that...Regardless, SOP as far as I can recall is a scolding and a link to the [C++FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types), which answers it quite nicely, though it requires reading.

Comment: Just an advice: function pointers are a **C Language feature** and not **C++**. You might want to consider looking on `std::function` or **Boost's** implementation.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino: They are also a C++ language feature.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, but is it considered a good practice to use raw function pointers in C++? I mean... it feels too much like C. It is like using `memcpy` on a C++ code when you have `std::copy`.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino: _Now_ you're right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks confusing and, personally, I believe that **C function pointers** look ugly on **C++'s OO implementation**. So I would advise you to use the `std::function`. It only has been available since `C++11`. If you cannot use it, try looking on [Boost's Implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/function.html).

I can give you an example of how to use the `std::function`:

```
bool MyFunction(int i)
{
    return i > 0;
}

std::function<bool(int)> funcPointer = MyFunction;
```

Using this you will drastically improve your code reliability. As of your problem, specifically:

```
class A
{
public:
    std::function<int*(const int&)> fun;
    A(std::function<int*(const int&)> f) : fun(f) {}
};

class B
{
private:
    float r;
    int *f(const int &t)
    {
        return new int(int(r) + t);
    }
    A *a;
    B()
    {

        std::function<int*(const int&)> tempFun = std::bind(&B::f, this, _1);
        a = new A(tempFun);
    }
};
```

You have to add the following namespace:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
```

Comment: I edited it. Try it now. (Code not tested... might need tweaks. But ask me if you have problems.)

Comment: it resulted in compiler error "no match for operator = of operand types"

Comment: The trick that does it is the `std::bind()` - transforming a pointer-to-member function into a free function (sort of), nice!

Answer (score 3):

> this result in compiler error

Because `f` is a `A`'s non-static member function returning `int*`, that accepts single const reference to `int`. That means, that its type is not:

```
int* (*)(const int &);
```

but:

```
int* (A::*)(const int&);
```

Also, your code signalizes very bad design - I think you need simple virtual function. But if you want to keep writing things this way, you may want to read: [ISOCPP: Pointers to members](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).

Remember, that non-static member functions of type `C` always accepts additional implicit argument of type `C*` (or `const C*`, if function is declared with `const` qualifier), that points to instance of `C` this function was called on.

Answer (score 1):

> So what to do

Not much. Other than templating `A` on the type of objects for which it will hold a pointer to a member function taking a reference to a const int and returning a pointer to int.

What you're trying to do is to mix a pointer to a free function with a pointer to member function. Whilst it sounds like they're both function pointers they're different enough to not be able to pass through the same type definition.